# Soft body squishing

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation, soft-body

I need to make a short animation displaying a soft paste bieng squished between two surfaces like the photo below.

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

[image: Paste bieng squished between two plates]

Comment: You can try soft body physics and modifiers such as Lattice and Mesh deform, but in the long run I'd suggest it easier and with far more control over shape and expansion, just using shapekeys and scaling keyframes.  At the link is a quick squish job doing it that way.  (the action is deliberately paused at each stage for demo)  The (imaginary) trowel in this case is larger than the blob itself, but can be any size and shape as can the blob's perimeter & thickness.  The link - 

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtkhCKZLZs_Pg2B5yTSXUCuHN6-K?e=fBWJf1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The squishing of glue can be simulated using fluids. The fluids are setup to be very viscous and a plate is pushed into it.

[image]

---

**Details - Blender 2.92**

1. Create the geometry for the model. A backplate to smear the adhesive onto, a spreader, and the initial glue shape.

[image]

2. Add a domain for the fluid simulation.

[image]

3. Setup the fluid domain. These setting will generate a thick fluid that does not flow much unless pressed and has some surface tension.

[image]

- also in the same panel, turn off gravity. This will prevent flow not driven by the force of the spreader.

[image]

4. Setup the spreader as a a fluid collision effector.

[image]

5. Setup the backplate as a fluid collision effector.

[image]

6. Setup the glue as a fluid geometry source.

[image]

7. Animate the movement of the spreader. In this case, a keyframe was entered at time=0 for the spreader to be above the glue. At time=100, a keyframe was entered for the spreader to be closer to the backplate.
8. Animate! The fluid simulation should be able to updated and complete in a few minutes.

---

Blender file available here - [image]